# How to add elements within an array based on information from another array in R?

Tags: r, arrays, sparse-matrix, memory-efficient

I have an array in which I need to add elements together based on the index in which they belong.

```
row_index <- c(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
array <- c(1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.2, 0.3, 5.6, 2.0, 3.1)
```

So in this case I want to add all elements that belong on the first row according to `row_index` together. For example, `1.2` and `5.6` would be added together since they correspond to the same row based on `row_index`and similarly for row 2 it would be `7.2 + 0.3`. So my resulting array would be.

```
result = (6.8 , 7.5 , 11.0 , 3.1)
```

I have no clue how to do this in R. For context, I have a sparse matrix and accessing which row each non-zero elements belongs to is very easy and efficient to do, and the length of `row_index` will always be the same as `array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `tapply` from `base R` where the grouping is based on 'row_index'

```
unname(tapply(array, row_index, FUN = sum))
#[1]  6.8  7.5 11.0  3.1
```

---

Or another is `by`

```
by(array, row_index, FUN = sum)
```

---

Or with `rowsum`

```
unname(rowsum(array, row_index)[,1])
#[1]  6.8  7.5 11.0  3.1
```

Or with `xtabs`

```
xtabs(array ~ row_index)
```

NOTE: All of the above solutions are from `base R`